# Lineart appears in front of other Grease Pencil objects. Any way to fix this?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, toon-shading, lineart

I'm trying to add a realtime outline to the 3d objects in my scene. The solidify modifier approach is kinda clunky, so I want to avoid it if possible. Next, I tried the grease pencil line art method, however, the added stroke appears in front of any other grease pencil objects (such as the dinosaurs in the screenshot below). Is there any way to fix that, or otherwise add stroke to objects?

*P.S: I've also tried the freestyle method, same result as lineart*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to fix the issue by unchecking the "In front" checkbox in the lineart object's viewport display settings and increasing the "Depth Offset" property in the Line Art modifier. Works like a charm!
[image]